# Why does Google Drive API returns incomplete response?

Tags: python, api, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm using [`google-api-python-client`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python) to call the Google Drive API.

According to [the API's spec](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#get), `get` should return a JSON with many fields. But my program only returns `id`, `name`, `mimeType` and `kind` as follows:

```
{
    "id": <omitted>,
    "name": "myfile.txt",
    "mimeType": "text/plain",
    "kind": "drive#file"
}
```

How do I get other metadata about a file using this API?

Comment: Google APIs don't return fields which are null containing no data.  try testing it in the try it at the bottom of this page.  https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right. I found the answer. The info on the spec page is incomplete. As pointed out in [another page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/performance), the API calls accept a `fields` parameter which specify the fields to return.